# How do you use UIPageVIewController and how can I change background of the PageControl? - Swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uipageviewcontroller, uipagecontrol

Being straight to the point I want to learn how to use UIPageViewController in Swift as well as how to be able to change the background of the PageControl given when you implement the following two functions:

```
func presentationCountForPageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController) -> Int {
  }

func presentationIndexForPageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController) -> Int {
  }
```

Here's a link to a project I found on github which has the PageControl background problem where even though the background of the ViewController is set to an image the PageControl still retains its own background color. (https://github.com/scroll318is/MyWeatherApp)

[PageControl Problem Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8SsHa.png)

I found an answer which only changes the background color issue that worked for someone but it's written in Objective-C and I have no idea how to implement it since I'm a beginner and all I know is Swift. Plus I'd like it to have the same background as any Image I put up.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary*)launchOptions { 
pageControl.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
UIPageControl *pageControl = [UIPageControl appearance];
pageControl.pageIndicatorTintColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
pageControl.currentPageIndicatorTintColor = [UIColor redColor];
}
```

Since I'm new to programming I tried looking around for tutorials and the only one I found which was exactly what I wanted was a Youtube tutorial on UIPageViewController by Vea Software. However it's outdated since it was written in Xcode 6.2 and he doesn't explain why certain functions are called.

Does anyone know why certain functions are called or know where I can learn UIPageViewController and especially how to change the background of the PageControl?

I've been playing around with the tutorial and repo from Github for a couple of days now trying to understand why certain functions are called but I'm struggling to understand anything.

I've looked on Online, Youtube, Stackoverflow and Apple's Documenation but the tutorials I've found online and Youtube don't dive too deep into the logic, resources on Stack are mostly in Objective-C which I'm having trouble converting to swift, and Apple's Docs don't tell you how to call them unless I'm just not looking in the right place.

Sorry for the long description and Thanks for any help guys.

Answer (score 1):

This should help you get a hang of it: https://spin.atomicobject.com/2015/12/23/swift-uipageviewcontroller-tutorial/

Once you finish that tutorial, you might want to try this one (http://www.theappguruz.com/blog/easy-steps-to-implement-uipageviewcontroller-in-swift) to get the hang of doing more inside of each view.

Comment: I'll check that out thanks! By the way would you know how to change the background on the UIPageViewController dots? The only way I've seen on some tutorials online is too implement a PageControl outlet and change to subviews to let it sit on top but I want to avoid that and try to use the dots that are already automatically implemented using UIPageViewController

Comment: @RichardCuico check out the first and second comments on the comments section from that first tutorial link. There's a really quick way to style your page dots! Let me know if you can't find it.

Comment: Awesome I saw it! I'll try to implement it as soon as I can. I currently have a lot of work being the last few weeks if school so it might take me awhile before I can give it a try but when i do I'll be sure to reply back and post my results. Thanks John!